# Facing problem of XMLDOMDocument2 in Tridion 2011

Tags: 2011

I am migrating Tridion version 2009 to 2011. My existing event code of the EventSystem
in Tridion 2009 for event named `OnPagePublishPost` is like below.

```cs
public void OnPagePublishPost(Tridion.ContentManager.Interop.TDS.Page page, IXMLDOMDocument2 publishResult, EventPhases phase) 
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(publishResult.xml);

    XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
    ns.AddNamespace("tcm", "http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0");
    ns.AddNamespace("xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");
    string publishOrUnpublish;
    publishOrUnpublish = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/tcm:PublishResponse/tcm:PublisherRequest/tcm:Instruction/@Title", ns).Value;
    EventHelper.WriteEventToHTMLLog("publishOrUnpublish: " + publishOrUnpublish);
    String pubTargUri = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/tcm:PublishResponse/tcm:PublisherRequest/tcm:PublicationTarget/@xlink:href", ns).Value;
    EventHelper.WriteEventToHTMLLog("pubTargUri: " + pubTargUri);

    string schemaID = Convert.ToString(page.ComponentPresentations[1].Component.Schema.ID;
}
```

Now when I subscribe this event using below code, shows me the error.

```cs
EventSystem.Subscribe<Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.Page,
                      PublishEventArgs>(OnPagePublishPost, EventPhases.Processed);
```

*Error Message*

> The best overloaded method match for 'Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.EventSystem.Subscribe<Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.Page,Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.Events.PublishEventArgs>(Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.TcmEventHandler<Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.Page,Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.Events.PublishEventArgs>, Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.EventPhases)' has some invalid arguments

I know something is going wrong with the parameter type `IXMLDOMDocument2`, but not getting how to solve this problem.

Comment: if the only change you made is indeed subscribing to an event and reusing the `OnPagePublishPost` code, then read the answer from @user978511, else I suggest you edit your question and add the rest of your 2011 event system code.

Comment: You can, of course, just keep using your old code and use the old event system. There's no need to change anything for Tridion 2011

Comment: @user978511 they could do that indeed, provided they also install the [legacy event adapter](http://sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/LegacyEventAdapter.aspx)

Comment: Hi Guys, It did not work for us, we took professional help from Tridion Support. Legacy event adapter does not make things work, we tried for a week making our existing event system work but in vain. At last we were told to convert the existing event system code to TOM.NET. So i do not agree that legacy event adapter is the key. We should stop saying this as Tridion support does not promote this.

Answer (score 4):

You are mixing 2 APIs here. As of Tridion 2011 SP1 there's a new event system based on TOM.NET, the previous event system was based on TOM.

You subscribe code:

```
EventSystem.Subscribe<Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.Page, PublishEventArgs>(OnPagePublishPost, EventPhases.Processed);
```

is from new event system, however your handler:

```
public void OnPagePublishPost(Tridion.ContentManager.Interop.TDS.Page page, IXMLDOMDocument2 publishResult, EventPhases phase) { //Code to execute }
```

Is expecting `TDS.Page` which is from TOM. The two worlds are not going to work together.

I suggest you reading some blog posts on new event system, like http://www.curlette.com/?p=90

Comment: Yes, I know that but actually that is the problem we are facing. We need to call that event in 2011, then what should we need to write. Because we are reading Xml content from the type IXMLDOMDocument2. And we use schema id from the Page type. My code is as - "public void OnPagePublishPost(Tridion.ContentManager.Interop.TDS.Page page, IXMLDOMDocument2 publishResult, EventPhases phase)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(publishResult.xml);
            string schemaID = Convert.ToString(page.ComponentPresentations[1].Component.Schema.ID;}"

Comment: @user927 pleased edit your question and add the code in there, this is not readable or useful in a comment. But before doing that, read the answer here again, do NOT try to mix TOM (or TOM Interop) and TOM.NET.

Comment: Would you help me now as per my given code in question? I need schema id and xml.

Answer (score 1):

First thing, error is not occurred due to `IXMLDOMDocument2`. If this is the case then error message will be different.

However, you are doing two mistakes:

1. As **@user978511** said you are mixing two API's
2. Subscribing and Calling function is not matching with the arguments

### How to Subscribe to an EventSystem?

Below is the code,

```
EventSystem.Subscribe<Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.Page, PublishEventArgs>(OnPagePublishPost, EventPhases.Processed);
```

### How to Create a Calling Method?

Currently you are passing two arguments which is why, below error is occurred.

> The best overloaded method match for 'Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.EventSystem.Subscribe(Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.TcmEventHandler, Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.EventPhases)' has some invalid arguments

You need to pass three arguments to the calling method that is `Page`, `PublishEventArgs` and `EventPhases`.

Below is the code,

```
public void OnPagePublishPost(Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.Page page, PublishEventArgs publishEventArgs, EventPhases phase)
{
    IXMLDOMDocument2 result = null;

    // Do Your Stuff 

    ProcessOnPagePublishPost(page, result);
}

public void ProcessOnPagePublishPost(Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.Page page, IXMLDOMDocument2 publishResult)
{
    // Execute your code further 
}
```

Hope this will help you.

### Update:

As per request, below is updated code to access the schema Id of the first component presentation

```
public void ProcessOnPagePublishPost(Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.Page page, IXMLDOMDocument2 publishResult)
{
    TcmUri schemaId = null;

    IList<ComponentPresentation> mComponentPresentations = page.ComponentPresentations;
    if (mComponentPresentations.Count > 0)
    {
        // Holds the first Component Presentation, Component's schema Id
        schemaId = mComponentPresentations[1].Component.Schema.Id;
    }

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(publishResult.xml);

    // Execute your code further 
}
```

### Update 2:

As per your further comments, my suggestion is not to use `IXMLDOMDocument2`. Access the `publishEventArgs.Targets` to read the information of Publishing Targets.

`OnPagePublishPost` will be called only, if the `Page` is Published.

```
EventSystem.Subscribe<Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.Page, PublishEventArgs>(OnPagePublishPost, EventPhases.Processed);

// This method will be calling only if Page is Published.
public void OnPagePublishPost(Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.Page page, PublishEventArgs publishEventArgs, EventPhases phase)
{
    TcmUri schemaId = null;

    IList<ComponentPresentation> mComponentPresentations = page.ComponentPresentations;
    if (mComponentPresentations.Count > 0)
    {
        // Holds the first Component Presentation, Component's schema Id
        schemaId = mComponentPresentations[1].Component.Schema.Id;
    }

    foreach (PublishingTarget publishingTarget in publishEventArgs.Targets)
    {
        String pubTargetTitle = publishingTarget.Title;
        TcmUri pubTargetId = publishingTarget.Id;

        // Do Your Stuff
    }
}
```

Hope this will help in understanding.

Comment: Would you help me now as per my given code in question? I need schema id and xml.

Comment: @Urvesh: Updated the answer to access the schema id and xml

Comment: Is typecasting possible From **Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.Page** to **Tridion.ContentManager.Interop.TDS.Page** and From **PublishEventArgs** to **IXMLDOMDocument2**

Comment: Thanks for the support. my half of the problem is resolved. But I am still not able to get xml data from type PublishEventArgs as in event method below two data types are not matched.

Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.Page page and

IXMLDOMDocument2 publishResult

Means, I want to typecasting

From Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.Page to Tridion.ContentManager.Interop.TDS.Page

and

From PublishEventArgs to IXMLDOMDocument2

Please suggest.

Comment: @Urvesh: Why you want to convert back to TOM (That is, `Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.Page` to `Tridion.ContentManager.Interop.TDS.Page` ). It looks like you are not migrating to 2011. You are just trying to wrap `TOM` around `TOM.Net`, which is wrong. While migrating any system, you need to change the old code accordingly to latest system.

Comment: @Urvesh: I have already given proper code related to 2011 event system. Only thing you need to do is to convert your functionality accordingly to 2011 event system. Clarify one thing, from where you are getting the publishResult and what is that contains?

Comment: Hi Shiva, In your sample code you assigned null value (IXMLDOMDocument2 result = null;), then how I shall get the information (publishResult.xml) is the concern. Please let me know on this. I am confused for that part of the code.

Comment: @Urvesh: `IXMLDOMDocument2 result = null;` is a declared and later you need to update it accordingly. Please confirm, why you are trying to use `IXMLDOMDocument2`? Are you on Framework 2.0 or 4.0?

Comment: We are working on framework 4.0. And our need to read xml from the component and update it as per our requirement and again need to update the updated xml in component.

Comment: @Urvesh: I have updated the answer with more information.